# Why is the definition of inductive set well defined?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, induction, intuition, natural-numbers

I've been studying from Enderton's *Mathematical Introduction to Logic* in which he defines an inductive set as follows:

> To simplify our discussion, we will consider an initial set $B \subseteq U$ and a class $F$ of functions containing just two members $f$ and $g$, where
>   $f:U×U→U$ and $g:U→U$.
>   Thus $f$ is a binary operation on $U$ and $g$ is a unary operation. (Actually $F$ need not be finite; it will be seen that our simplified discussion here is, in fact, applicable to a more general situation. $F$ can be any set of relations on $U$, and in Chapter 2 this greater generality will be utilized. But the case discussed here is easier to visualize and is general enough to illustrate the ideas. For a less restricted version, see Exercise 3.)
>   If $B$ contains points $a$ and $b$, then the set $C$ we wish to construct will contain, for example,
>   $b, f (b, b), g(a), f (g(a), f (b, b)), g( f (g(a), f (b, b)))$.
>   Of course these might not all be distinct. The idea is that we are given certain bricks to work with, and certain types of mortar, and we want $C$ to contain just the things we are able to build.
>
> In defining $C$ more formally, we have our choice of two definitions. We can define it “from the top down” as follows: Say that a subset $S$ of $U$ is closed under $f$ and $g$ iff whenever elements $x$ and y belong to $S$ , then so also do $f(x,y)$ and $g(x)$.Say that $S$ is inductive iff $B \subseteq S$ and $S$ is closed under $f$ and $g$ . Let $C^*$ be the intersection of all the inductive subsets of $U$; thus $x \in C^*$ iff $x$ belongs to every inductive subset of $U$. It is not hard to see (and the reader should check) that $C^*$ is itself inductive. Furthermore, $C^*$ is the smallest such set, being included in all the other inductive sets.
>
> The second (and equivalent) definition works “from the bottom up.” We want $C_*$ to contain the things that can be reached from $B$ by applying $f$ and $g$ a finite number of times. Temporarily define a construction sequence to be a finite sequence $<x_1, . . . , x_n>$ of elements of $U$ such that
>   for each $i \leq n$ we have at least one of
>
> $x_i \in B$,
>
> $x_i=f(x_j,x_k)$ for some $j<i,k<i$,
>
> $x_i =g(x_j)$ for
>   some $j<i$.
>
> In other words, each member of the sequence either is in B or results from earlier members by applying f or g. Then let C be the set of all points x such that some construction sequence ends with x.

I am confused as in other texts I've read an inductive set to be defined in a similar fashion to as follows from Enderton's *Elements of Set Theory*:

> A set $A$ is said to be inductive iff $\emptyset \in A$ and it is "closed under successor," i.e.,
>   $(\forall a \in A) a^+ \in a$

or similarly for [For Natural Numbers](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Inductive_Set)

What confuses me most is that by just defining an inductive set as such "$S$ is inductive iff $B \subseteq S$ and $S$ is closed under $f$ and $g$" doesnt that lead to inductive sets such as $\{1,2,3,4\}$ where $f$ and $g$ can be sent to map all to the same element $1$.

What is the advantage to this type of definition for induction and how is it consistent with other definition. Using this definition of induction how may one say that the natural numbers are an inductive set any more than my finite set above. What is the intuition in this definition?

Thank you for help.

Comment: Presumably that first definition has some restriction on $f,g$.

Comment: Not very clear... The first def is used with $f$ a binery connective (conjunction) and $g$ a unary one (negation) and $B$ the initial set of propositional letters. The general form of def can be specialized to *natural* numbers with $B = \{ 0 \}$ and only one unary function : the *successor* function.

Comment: The equivalent "bottom up" def for naturals is : $\mathbb N$ is the intersection of all sets that contain $0$ and are closed under successor.

Comment: @Ian please see the edits above, I have added in how the author defines $f$ and $g$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I understand the bottom up definition a bit better, this top down definition is a bit more confusing for me. I understand it is possible to construct the inductive set of natural numbers using this definition however it also appears possible to construct a finite inductive set of natural numbers.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA But by Endertons definition $S$  needs to only be closed under $f$ and $g$, which it would be by mapping every element back to a single element in the set. Please correct me where I am misinterpreting the definition provided by Enderton.

Comment: There are many definitions of inductive set. In that book it looks like they are preparing to do induction on well-founded sets. There is no problem with finite sets satisfying the definition.

Comment: $\{1,2,3,4\}$ with your unary relation mapping all elements to $1$ is perfectly inductive. One only needs to take the initial set to be $\{2,3,4\}$. One can do induction on it by first checking a property on the initial set, and then if the induction step is satisfied, then the property would have to be satisfied for $1$ as well.

Comment: @logarithm If finite sets are permissible wouldn't that be inconsistent with the traditional definition of induction on Natural Numbers. Wouldn't we have created an alternate system of induction.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I dont see why induction should not be generalized to be able to handle both sets of logical formulas and connectives as well as natural numbers. In an abstract sense they are both elements building on one another.

Comment: It is just induction on finite posets. What is the problem with that? Take a look at [induction on well-founded sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-founded_relation#Induction_and_recursion). There is no restriction on the cardinality of the set.

Comment: @logarithm wouldnt that be inconsistent with induction on the natural numbers. For instance lets take the infinite case where I define g to be the unary operation mapping each element back onto itself which is still consistent with being closed under g. Then surely we wouldn't be able to have induction in the traditional sense on natural numbers.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA a recursive definition is still dependent on traditional induction and even so it is only as good as a well defined recursion relation

Comment: @user372382 For that $g$ then the inductive set would be just the initial set. Induction would work by checking a property on the initial set. The induction step wouldn't be necessary. Yes, it is different. Just like it is different when the initial set consists of more than one element. In the naturals the initial set is only $0$. So, the initial step of the induction consists in checking only that element. But in other well-founded sets, one would need to check all minimal elements.

Comment: But how can these definitions be consistent even more so how is Endertons more useful than just having an initial set and a successor operation. By the conditions being so loose on what is classified as an inductive set isn't it possible their intersection may result in $\emptyset$

Comment: Definitions from different people don't need to be consistent. Is that the same author?

Comment: What is more so confusing is that both of those definitions are from two different text books both written by enderton one about logic and the other about set theory. Would it not be possible to prove that the empty set is an inductive set from this definition as well if B were $\emptyset$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA on the following page Enderton gives examples of both the natural numbers and formulas conforming to his definition of induction. I dont see why the concept of induction has to be mutually exclusive between sets of expressions or sets numbers.

Comment: The word "inductive" is just being used for two different but related things. Context is relevant. When I talk about "functions" in set theory, I mean something quite different than when I talk about "functions" in type theory or logic, even though they look quite similar and have close relations. This is a very common occurrence in mathematics. Presumably it becomes clear that Enderton is using this definition in a very different way that's not restricted to just $\omega$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enderton is giving a very general *definition template* for different kinds of inductive sets. The actual definition of inductive depends on the choice of $B$ and $F$.

Maybe it would be clearer to write it like this: Let $B$ be a set and $F$ a class of functions. A set $S$ is $(B,F)$-inductive if $B\subseteq S$ and $S$ is closed under all the functions in $F$.

Now as a particular case of this definition template, we can take $B = \{\emptyset\}$ and $F = \{s\}$, where $s$ is the unary function on sets defined by $s(x) = x\cup \{x\}$. Then a set $S$ is $(\{\emptyset\},\{s\})$-inductive if and only if $\emptyset\in S$ and for all $x\in S$, also $s(x)\in S$. So $\omega$ is the least $(\{\emptyset\},\{s\})$-inductive set.

But there are many other instances of this definition template, with many different results. You suggest another example at the end of your question: If $B = \emptyset$ and $F = \{f,g\}$, where $f$ and $g$ are constant functions with output $1$, then a set $S$ is $(B,F)$-inductive if and only if $S = \emptyset$ or $1\in S$. So yes, $\{1,2,3,4\}$ is $(B,F)$-inductive. Enderton is *not* claiming that this notion of $(B,F)$-inductive has anything to do with the example above in which $\omega$ is the least inductive set.

> What is the advantage to this type of definition for induction and how is it consistent with other definition.

The advantage to this definition is that it's very general, handling not just induction for the natural numbers, but many other example of the same type in mathematics. Different instances of the definition (for different $B$ and $F$) are inconsistent with each other, but they are all instances of the same abstract pattern.

Comment: I would ignore the framing of "the advantage" in your final paragraph. They're just talking about different (but related) things. One isn't "more advantageous" than the other. It's like saying the notion of a field is "more/less advantageous" than the notion of the real numbers.

Comment: @DerekElkins One definition is more abstract than the other, and I believe there's an inherent advantage to abstraction...

Comment: The distinction is between a framework and an instance of the framework, not between two different frameworks. The reals are an instance of a field, but that doesn't mean it would be advantageous (or even make sense) to replace the concept of the reals with that of a field. I can't learn everything I want to know about the reals/$\omega$ by studying general properties of fields/general inductive sets. It's not like set theorists don't know that they could generalize their notion of inductive set, they're just more interested in the details of $\omega$ than generalities about inductive sets.

Comment: @DerekElkins Of course there are advantages to specializations as well as generalizations. The question asked was "what's the advantage of this definition?" The answer is: "it's more abstract, so it unifies many examples." Do you really disagree with this?

Comment: One doesn't do away with the concept of the reals when one defines the notion of a general field. Of course it's hugely advantageous to understand the general notion of field: then you're free to continue studying the reals, while also seeing how they fit into the broader mathematical landscape.

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer I greatly appreciate your taking the time to explain. I am a bit confused by the final example in which $B = \emptyset$  and $f,g$  map to $1$. If $S = \emptyset$  wouldn't mapping to anything contradict having a closure on $S$ ? Also wouldn't including $\emptyset$  in the set of inductive sets result in an empty intersection?

Comment: @AlexKruckman I don't disagree that it is a definition that unifies many examples. Advantages are *relative to* something else. The question is "what's the advantage of this definition *over the other one*". This framing suggests that both definitions are an option, and it's a matter of deciding which you prefer. The point of my comments is that they are talking about different things and therefore are not interchangeable. You typically just don't have the option of using one in place of the other. You're going to use the relevant one regardless of what nice aspects the other may have.

Comment: @user372382 (1) In that example, $\emptyset$ is *vacuously* closed under $f$ and $g$. Remember, to say that $S$ is closed under $g$ means that for all $s\in S$, $g(s)\in S$. If $S$ is empty, then there are no elements $s$ to check, so the condition is satisfied. (2) Yes, in that example, the least inductive set is empty. That's fine - not every instance of the notion of $(B,F)$-inductive set is interesting!

Comment: I apologize for my confusion, how would we be able to map $\emptyset$ to $1$ under $f$ and $g$ without breaking the closure of $S$ if  $S = \emptyset$? If $S = \emptyset$ which implies $C^* = \emptyset$ as well would it still be possible to construct $C_*$ to be $\emptyset$ . Thank you for all of your time and patience in clarifying this concept.

Comment: @user372382 there's a difference between $\emptyset$ and $\{\emptyset\}$. The former has no elements to plug into $f$ and $g$, so it's vacuously closed. I don't know what the notations $C_*$ and $C^*$ refer to.

Comment: My apologies for not properly formatting the notation in the definition originally. It is a construction based on initial elements and building up as opposed to taking subsets of a larger set. I am still a bit confused wouldn't mapping $\emptyset$ to $1$ be mapping to an element outside of $S = \emptyset$ unless $1 \in S$ but then $S \ne \emptyset$?

Comment: Taking a step back: We have functions $f: U\times U\to U$ and $g: U\to U$ defined by $f(x,y) = 1$ and $g(x) = 1$. We say a set $S$ is closed under $F = \{f,g\}$ if (1) for all elements $a,b\in S$, $f(a,b)\in S$, and (2) for all elements $c\in S$, $g(c)\in S$. The set $S = \emptyset$ satisfies these conditions, because there are no elements in $S$ to apply the functions to! On the other hand, $S = \{\emptyset\}$ is *not* $F$-closed, because, for example, $g(\emptyset) = 1\notin S$. Do you see the distinction?